# Set Cover - A Couple Different Versions

Tags: algorithm

I've been working with a bipartite graph with two sets of vertices L and R, and an edge-set E. There are a couple different problems I've been attempting to solve:

1) The simple set cover problem (i.e. find the smallest cardinality subset of vertices in L, such that the neighborhood of that subset contains all of R). As I understand, this problem is known as the hitting set problem and is equivalent to the set cover problem and some approximation algorithms exist. I wanted to know what approximation algorithm you would recommend, I've found a couple different ones online.

2) The second problem I wanted to solve is similar to the above, but instead of describing all of R, I want to describe only T, a subset of R, without any other elements of R. In addition, the allowed operations include set unions and set difference and set intersections of the neighborhoods of elements of L. Thus, I want to find the minimum number of elements in L that must be included in such a description. Apologies if this is unclear, I can explain further and respond to any questions.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: For 2, is it the number of distinct elements of L that are included in the formula or the number of elements with duplicates?

Comment: Also, could set complement be allowed? It might simplify the algorithms.

Comment: Number of distinct elements, and set complements are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, I recommend [integer linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Integer_linear_program_formulation). There are many solvers out there; I've personally used GLPK (free) and CPLEX (commercial).

For 2, intuitively, we want the Venn diagram induced by the chosen sets to have the property that no area contains both an element in T and an element not in T. (I'm assuming in addition to set complement that we are allowed the empty set in the formula.) We can reduce this problem to a simple set cover problem as follows. The new elements to be covered are the two element sets {x, y} for all x in T and y in R - T. Each old set S gives rise to one new set `{{x, y} | x in S and y in R - S}`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you recommend I code an approximation algorithm for the second question?

Comment: @PranavReddy Integer linear programming.